# Ingress -> Cluster IP back-end - got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I got ingress defined as:

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: wp-ingress
      namespace: wordpress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 25m
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: my.domain.com
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /
                backend:
                  serviceName: wordpress
                  servicePort: 6002
```

And the back-end, defined as `Cluster IP` running on 6002 port.

When I am trying to reach ingress by its ADDRESS in the browser I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I suspect it has to do with the back-end?

**Q: What could be a problem? How to analyse it? to make it work.**

See the picture below, it is on GCP, all ips are resolved. All seems connected to each other.

The `nginx-ingress` (ingress-controller, default backed) was installed as helm chart.

```
helm install --namespace wordpress --name wp-nginx-ingress stable/nginx-ingress   --tls
```

**UPDATE:**

I do not use yet (https) for back-end, tried to remove http redirect from the ingress yml: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"` removed - did not help.

[image]

**UPDATE2**: wordpress yaml - got from running service at `yaml tab` in GCP->KE->Services

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-30T04:11:12Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: wordpress
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Tiller
    app.kubernetes.io/name: wordpress
    helm.sh/chart: wordpress-9.0.4
  name: wordpress
  namespace: wordpress
  resourceVersion: "2518308"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/wordpress/services/wordpress
  uid: 7dac1a73-723c-11ea-af1a-42010a800084
spec:
  clusterIP: xxx.xx.xxx.xx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 6002
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: wordpress
    app.kubernetes.io/name: wordpress
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

**UPDATE: 3**

I tried:

1. `kubectl -n wordpress exec -it  wordpress-xxxx-xxxx -- /bin/bash`
2. `curl http://wordpress.wordpress.svc.cluster.local:6002` and it works - it gets me the html from the wordpress.

Comment: Do you have TLS configured on the backend? It does not look like you have it configured for the ingress.

Comment: no.not yet. I wanted to make it work with http for now. as first step. to have less moving parts. is it required?

Comment: No, but you should remove the SSL redirect if you don't have SSL configured

Comment: What happens when you try to reach the backend directly from another pod in the cluster? Do not go through the Ingress

Comment: add wordpress service yaml...and output of kubectl describe wordpress. add logs from nginx ingress controller

Comment: verify if the pod is actually listening on port 443 and 6002

Comment: Does it work when you run `curl http://wordpress.wordpress.svc.cluster.local:6002` from another `Pod` in your cluster or `curl http://<ClusterIP_of_your_wordpress_Service>:6002` directly from any of your `GKE` nodes ?