# How to deploy Jaeger on Kubernetes GKE

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, jaeger

I have added these fields in application.yml of microservices and dependency in pom.xml.Jaeger running on my local is abl to identify the services as well

```
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=localhost
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831
```

I have deployed all my microservices on kubernetes. Please help me in deploying jaeger on kubernetes.

**UPDATE:**
I have reached this step. I have a load balancer IP for jaeger-query. But on which host and port will my microservice send the logs to  ??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link for steps to deploy JAEGER on kubernetes .

> https://www.upnxtblog.com/index.php/2018/07/16/kubernetes-tutorial-distributed-tracing-with-jaeger/

make following changes in application.properties

```
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=<load_balancer_ip> of your jaeger service
opentracing.jaeger.http-sender.url=http://<jaeger-collector-service-name>:port/api/traces
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Jaeger Operator](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.16/operator/) to deploy Jaeger on kubernetes.The Jaeger Operator is an implementation of a Kubernetes Operator. Operators are pieces of software that ease the operational complexity of running another piece of software. More technically, Operators are a method of packaging, deploying, and managing a Kubernetes application

Comment: error while evaluating the ingress spec: service "default/jaeger-query" is type "ClusterIP", expected "NodePort" or "LoadBalancer"

Comment: I followed all the steps provided in the link. I got the above error

Comment: you are on gke..use nginx ingress instead of gke ingress..add kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx annotation....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572249/why-does-google-cloud-show-an-error-when-using-clusterip

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link for a better understanding - https://www.upnxtblog.com/index.php/2018/07/16/kubernetes-tutorial-distributed-tracing-with-jaeger/